# locally finite subset $A$ of a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces, differential-topology

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a locally finite family in a metric space $ (Y, d) $.

Show that the function

$y   \rightarrow$ Sup $\{d (y, Y \setminus A): A \in \mathcal{A}\}$ defined from $Y $ in $\overline{R}$ is continuous. Here $\overline{R}$ denotes the line extended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: Let $f:Y\to\overline{\Bbb R}:y\mapsto\sup\{d(y,Y\setminus A:A\in\mathscr{A}\}$.

Note that for any $y\in Y$ and $S\subseteq Y$, $d(y,S)=0$ iff $y\in\operatorname{cl}S$. Thus, for any $A\in\mathscr{A}$ we have $d(y,Y\setminus A)>0$ iff $y\notin\operatorname{cl}(Y\setminus A)$, which is the case iff $y\in Y\setminus\operatorname{cl}(Y\setminus A)=\operatorname{int}A$. For each $y\in Y$ let $$\mathscr{A}(y)=\{A:A\in\mathscr{A}\text{ and }y\in\operatorname{int}A\}\,.$$

- Show that $f(y)=\max\{d(y,Y\setminus A):A\in\mathscr{A}(y)\}$.
- Show that $\bigcap\{\operatorname{int}A:A\in\mathscr{A}(y)\}$ is an open nbhd of $y$ and therefore contains some open ball $B(y,r_y)$ centred at $y$.
- Show further that we can choose $r_y$ small enough so that for each $A\in\mathscr{A}$, $B(y,r_y)\cap A\ne\varnothing$ iff $y\in\operatorname{cl}A$.
- Show that if $z\in B(y,r_y)$, then $|f(z)-f(y)|\le d(z,y)$.

Use these results to show that $f$ is continuous at each point $y\in Y$ and therefore is continuous.

Comment: I have tried to move forward with the second suggestion and I can't prove it, could you help me with any recommendations?

Comment: @Us12: The second bullet point? It follows from the same fact that justifies the first one, namely, that $\mathscr{A}(y)$ is finite — and that follows from the local finiteness of $\mathscr{A}$.

Comment: That is, this arbitrary intersection becomes finite and therefore a finite intersection of openings, which would imply me open, am I wrong?

Comment: @Us12: Yes, that’s right: it’s the intersection of finitely many open nbhds of $y$, so it **is** an open nbhd of $y$.